# Authenticated proxies on HAProxy load balancer

Tags: haproxy

I want to rotate between a few http authenticated proxies. But I am unable to plug this into the config file because the url structure is different. It works when i remove the username and pass (but requesting the username and pass of course). Is there a way to send the credentials? If i don't add them i am getting a 407 proxy auth error.

```
global
        daemon
        maxconn 500

defaults
        mode http
        timeout connect 5000ms
        timeout client 50000ms
        timeout         server 50000ms

frontend rotatingproxies
        bind *:3000
        default_backend rotateproxy
        option http_proxy
        option http-use-proxy-header

backend rotateproxy
        option http_proxy 
        server proxyserver user:pass@domain.com:9999
        server proxyserver user:pass@domain.com:9999

        balance roundrobin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not work this way. You need real server address. If you want to add a user-name and password, there is a solution. You need to first encode them in base64 by hand and add the resulting string in the Proxy-Authorization header. For instance :

```
$ echo -n user:pass | openssl enc -a
dXNlcjpwYXNz

backend rotateproxy
   server proxy1 ip1:9999
   server proxy2 ip2:9999
   reqadd Proxy-Authorization:\ Basic\ dXNlcjpwYXNz
```

Your client will have to use haproxy as an explicit proxy however, and you need to remove
"option http_proxy".

Comment: This answer doesn't work for redirects since HAProxy passes headers during the first request of a TCP session only. The solution is to pass the credentials as part of the balancer url: `HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@localhost:3000`. For more details see https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2481.

Answer (score 0):

I searched through the [HAProxy-1.3 documentation](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/doc/configuration.txt), and it does not seem to support what you are asking for.

If you have access to the backend server, I would suggest turning authentication off there, and adding another web-server, e.g. nginx, in front of HAProxy to only do basic http authentication.